# Копирование в буфер из Memo и наоборот

Tags: delphi, компоненты

Подскажите, как содержимое компоненты Мемо1 скопировать в буфер? И как это содержимое при нажатии другой кнопки вставить в Мемо2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот статья](http://devdelphi.ru/?p=278) по работе с буфером обмена из Delphi

```
uses ...Clipbrd;\\ Подключили модуль

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClipBoard:=TClipboard.Create;\\ Создали объект
   ClipBoard.SetTextBuf(memo1.lines.text);\\Скопировали в буфер обмена текст
    if ClipBoard.FormatCount=4 then memo2.lines.text:=ClipBoard.AsText;\\ проверили если в буфере текст то вставили его в memo2 
  ClipBoard.Clear;\\Очистили после себя буфер обмена
 ClipBoard.free; \\  удалили объект
end;
```

Comment: может я конечно так сказать "наглею",но..
ClipBoard:=TClipboard.Create;\\ Создали объект
( Left side cannot be assigned to)


   ClipBoard.SetTextBuf(memo1.lines.text);\\Скопировали в буфер обмена текст
(Undeclared identifier: 'StrToChr' )

если со второй ошибкой я еще вижу шансы справиться,то с первой..увы(
взываю о помощи..

Comment: Конечно наглеете, что лень было почитать статью и включить мозг?

первое 
  
    **TClipboard.Create;** просто без **ClipBoard:=**

Второе 

    **ClipBoard.SetTextBuf(memo1.Lines.GetText)** вместо **ClipBoard.SetTextBuf(memo1.Lines.Text)**

Ну и естественно коментарии слешем в другую сторону , совсем ни хотите думать

Comment: то что комментарии слешем в другую сторону мне Delphi подсказал)

Comment: спасибо все отлично получилось)
обязательно почитаю статью ;)

Answer (score 0):

В цикле, построчно.

Comment: детальнее пожалуйста,как обратится к буферу? 
и прочие мелочи,так как опыта работы с буфером вообще не имею..

Comment: Вы уверенны, что буфер - необходим. Вот так безо всякого буфера:
int c = Memo1->Lines->Count;
for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
  Memo2->Lines->Add(Memo1->Lines->Strings[i]);

Comment: Ваш код на С, человек просил на Delphi

Comment: на Делфи это будет выглядеть примерно так?
<pre> for i=0 to (а что здесь?) do inc(i);
Memo2.Lines.Add(Memo1.Lines.Strings[i]);</pre>

Comment: Совсем ни так :)

    for i:=0 to memo1.Lines.Count-1 do memo2.Lines.Add(memo1.Lines.Strings[i]);

Но это не работа через буфер, а построчное копирование с одного  memo в другое

Comment: я знаю,с буфером еще разобраться надо(не люблю сдавать лабы если не понимаю в ней все до строчки)поэтому придется пойти легким путем..
хотя..нада как я говорил на 2 кнопки разбить код(одна вырезает содержимое,а другая вставляет),хотя хотя спасибо,дальше буду думать сам!

Answer (score 0):

```
Memo.CopyToCliboard
Memo.PasteFromClipboard
```

Comment: Это на каком языке???

Comment: это delphi))

Comment: кто-то был заминусовал,хотя вполне рабочий код если подключен модуль Clipbrd